# Import classes into the global scope

Tags: javascript, typescript

I am trying to import a class into the global scope, and I am able to do it, but then when I try to extend the class I get an error saying:

> Type 'any' is not a constructor function type.

So this is what I am doing to get that error:

**main.ts**

```
const MyClass = require('./core/MyClass');

class MyTestClass extends MyClass {

}
```

I then tried using `import MyClass from './core/MyClass'`, instead of a const, but that seems as if it is only within the scope of the current file, which doesn't help me either.

**core/MyClass.ts**

```
export default class MyClass {

}
```

I have tried using namespaces which works the way I want in typescript, but once compiled into javascript the namespace is undefined.

Is there a way I can import my class into the global scope and not get the error above when extending the class?

Comment: you can always do `window.MyClass = MyClass` if you want to declare global var in browser.

Comment: doing that I get `Cannot find name 'MyClass'.`

Comment: is it with `import` or `require`?

Comment: Like this: `import MyClass = require('./core/MyClass');
window['MyClass'] = MyClass;`

Comment: try `import MyClass from './core/MyClass'`.  Then create property on `window`

Comment: That works on the current file scope but not global scope. In the global scope I still get this `Cannot find name 'MyClass'`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your code you have :

```
require('./core/MyClass');
```

If you don't have `import / export` in your file then TypeScript assumes the file is *global*. However depending upon your usage of the file (e.g in NodeJS or if using a bundler like webpack) **the file is still a module and not global**.

Cool, with that out of the way you can put something on the global like:

```
export default class MyClass {
}
(global as any).MyClass = MyClass;
```

Be sure to include `node.d.ts` to get `global`.

## More

And of course I would also like to warn against `default` as the `const / require` you wrote is also wrong. You need something like `const {default} = require('module/foo');`. More: https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/content/docs/tips/defaultIsBad.html

Comment: Thank you this works perfectly! I have been searching for this for a few days now!